# Get make to show line number on error

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile, which is missing an ldflag. I know how to fix it, but I don't know which line in the makefile the error is generated on.

```
+ make
  CCLD   test
test-test.o: In function `write_png':
/home/lenovo/scratch/libass/test/test.c:52: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
...
/home/lenovo/scratch/libass/test/test.c:57: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

How do I get make to print out the line the error is on?

(If anybody is wondering, it is a makefile from the libass project in the test directory.)

Comment: Show us your makefile. `make` won't tell you the makefile's line because it can only be on the linking command.

Comment: You can find the libass library here http://code.google.com/p/libass/ . I was building the makefile in the test directory. I know the missing library is -lpng as I can correctly run the wrong command from make V=1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `remake` to see if it helps.

http://static.usenix.org/events/lisa11/tech/full_papers/Bernstein.pdf

Heres an example obtained from the link above:

[image]

Hope this helps!